# VirtualBox Kernel Service Is Not Running

Tags: virtualbox

I am using oracle virtualbox.  I have installed the Virtualbox as well as Guest Additionls and built oracle linux VM. However, after I restarted the system, I got an error after successful reboot "notification in the linux VM to be precise" that says "Virtualbox Kernel service is not running".  I checked the log /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log   and it said "restart guest or host".  I did restarted both but the issue persists.  I don't know where to start to investigate.  Please assist.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x41u7.png)

Comment: You do not say anything about what host (and x86 or 64 bit) or guest (and x86 or 64-bit). Did you enable Hardware Virtualization in the Host BIOS?

Comment: @John, the host is windows 10 64 bit and guest is Oracle linux 64 bit.  Hardware virtualization in the host is enabled already.

Comment: Try a fresh ISO download for Oracle Linux and try a different guest machine (to see if somehow Vbox is the issue)